# How to use np.where between dataframes of different sizes? 'operands could not be broadcast together'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two dataframes of different sizes.

`df1` has addresses and no zipcodes.
`df2` has address and zipcodes.

I am trying to match addresses from `df1` to `df2` using `np.where`, and if there's a match, bring the corresponding zipcode over to `df1`.

However I've just realized that this doesn't work with different size dataframes.

First dataframe with no zipcodes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'address1':['1 o\'toole st','2 main st','3 high street','5 foo street','10 foo street'],
                   'address2':['town1',np.nan,np.nan,'Bartown',np.nan],
                   'address3':[np.nan,'village','city','county2','county3']})
df1['zipcode']=''
print(df1)

        address1 address2 address3 zipcode
0   1 o'toole st    town1      NaN        
1      2 main st      NaN  village        
2  3 high street      NaN     city        
3   5 foo street  Bartown  county2        
4  10 foo street      NaN  county3
```

Second dataframe from where I want to get zipcodes from:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'address1':['1 o\'toole st','2 main st','7 mill street','5 foo street','10 foo street','asda'],
                   'address2':['town1','village','city','Bartown','county3','efsefs'],
                   'address3':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'county2','USA','asdasd'],
                   'zipcode': ['er45','qw23','rt67','yu89','yu83','aedsa']})
print(df2)

        address1 address2 address3 zipcode
0   1 o'toole st    town1      NaN    er45
1      2 main st  village      NaN    qw23
2  7 mill street     city      NaN    rt67
3   5 foo street  Bartown  county2    yu89
4  10 foo street  county3      USA    yu83
5           asda   efsefs   asdasd   aedsa
```

Filling in `df1['zipcode']`column using `np.where`. If both addresses match, return `df2['zipcode']` else `'no_match'`:

```
df1['zipcode'] = np.where(df1['address1'].isin(df2['address1']), df2['zipcode'], 'no_match')



ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-176-499624d43d5c> in <module>
----> 1 df1['zipcode'] = np.where(df1['address1'].isin(df2['address1']), df2['zipcode'], 'no_match')
      2 df1

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (6,) ()
```

Is it possible to do this with 'np.where' and different size dataframes? Or is there a better way of searching for a match and bringing across the zipcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with new column `key` created by `fillna`, for no match get missing values, so last add `fillna('no_match')`:

```
df1['key'] = df1['address1'] + df1['address2'].fillna(df1['address3'])
df2['key'] = df2['address1'] + df2['address2'].fillna(df2['address3'])

df1['zipcode'] =  df1['key'].map(df2.set_index('key')['zipcode']).fillna('no_match')

print (df1)
        address1 address2 address3                   key   zipcode
0   1 o'toole st    town1      NaN     1 o'toole sttown1      er45
1      2 main st      NaN  village      2 main stvillage      qw23
2  3 high street      NaN     city     3 high streetcity  no_match
3   5 foo street  Bartown  county2   5 foo streetBartown      yu89
4  10 foo street      NaN  county3  10 foo streetcounty3      yu83
```

Comment: I get the error: 'InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects' on the full dataset. This is because some of the addresses are not unique. Such as `Main Street, Sometown`. There might be two `keys` with `mainstreetsometown` so they can't be used as indexes. that's just the messy data i am working with.

Comment: @SCool - it means there are duplicates in `df2['key'],`  possible solution is remove duplicated rows by `df1['zipcode'] =  df1['key'].map(df2.drop_duplicates('key').set_index('key')['zipcode']).fillna('no_match')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a merge:

```
df_new = df1.merge(df2[['address1', 'zipcode']], on='address1', how='left')
df_new = df_new.fillna('no_match')
```

Comment: I'll try that out. Potentially I have ...? You didn't finish the sentence.

Comment: Ah, that was about the fillna, which I then included.